# Integral inequality and sup norm

Tags: integration, inequality, normed-spaces

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a positive smooth function on $[0,1]^2$ such that if we define $A(x)=\int_0^1\,f(x,y)dy$, then $A$ is strictly increasing and $A(1)=1+\beta>1$. Now suppose $v$ is smooth, positive and increasing (if needed you can also assume concave down), so that $||v||_{\infty}=v(1)=v^*$. Is it true that the sup norm of $w(x)=\int_0^1 f(x,y)v(y)dy$ is strictly greater than $v^*$?